# How to resolve problem with StackOverflowException on MVC Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, exception, iis, .net-core

There is problem with hosting application on IIS by VS2017 (15.9.3). I have MVC app write in .NET Core 2.0 with enabled logging on web.config

> stdoutLogEnabled="true" stdoutLogFile="c:\Logs\log.txt"

After any request is made I get 502.3 error.

> HTTP Error 502.3 - Bad Gateway The specified CGI application
>   encountered an error and the server terminated the process.

On my log file there is short info:

> Process is terminating due to StackOverflowException.

On EventViewer I get more descriptive error:

> Faulting application name: w3wp.exe, version: 7.5.7601.17514, time
>   stamp: 0x4ce7afa2
>
> Faulting module name: ntdll.dll, version: 6.1.7601.24260, time stamp:
>   0x5b9470be
>
> Exception code: 0xc000070a
>
> Fault offset: 0x00000000000139d7
>
> Faulting process id: 0x2304
>
> Faulting application start time: 0x01d48723e2a88740
>
> Faulting application path: c:\windows\system32\inetsrv\w3wp.exe
>
> Faulting module path: C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll
>
> Report Id: f7ca32d0-f31c-11e8-83db-1c4d70da3d0a

Exception is probably generated by something in my code, maybe configuration of sth is wrong, but how can I find reason of it?

What could be the best strategy to find solution?

Comment: how often do you get the Exception? Have you tried attaching to the IIS process from visual studio to enable you to catch \ debug the issue?

Comment: Exception occurs all time, I cannot attach do debug

Comment: is there anything in your event viewer?

Comment: @SimonPrice: yes, look at my post, there is section "On EventViewer I get more descriptive error:"

Comment: Do you have the same issues when running via the dotnet CLI? This might give you more information on the console.